# I get error when i execute amfphp file

Tags: php, flash, amfphp

I have one page in my site with flash, but I have a problem.
When I try to execute dircetly the file site.com/amfphp/gateway.php I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'VerboseException' with message
>   'Non-static method CharsetHandler::setMethod() should not be called
>   statically, assuming $this from incompatible context' in ....

```
function service() {

//Set the parameters for the charset handler
CharsetHandler::setMethod($this->_charsetMethod); // the problem point here
CharsetHandler::setPhpCharset($this->_charsetPhp);
CharsetHandler::setSqlCharset($this->_charsetSql);

//Attempt to call charset handler to catch any uninstalled extensions
$ch = new CharsetHandler('flashtophp');
$ch->transliterate('?');

$ch2 = new CharsetHandler('sqltophp');
$ch2->transliterate('?');
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe try calling the method on each object instead? `$ch->setMethod($this->_charsetMethod);`

Comment: I will call it, but what parameters should i put 
`$ch = new ChasetHandler(' HERE ');`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the setMethod function of the CharsetHandler class isn't static. That means you can't call it unless you have an instance of that class. Alexander's suggestion to call setMethod on each of the two instances is appropriate. Your code should read:

```
function service() {

    //Set the parameters for the charset handler
    CharsetHandler::setPhpCharset($this->_charsetPhp);
    CharsetHandler::setSqlCharset($this->_charsetSql);

    //Attempt to call charset handler to catch any uninstalled extensions
    $ch = new CharsetHandler('flashtophp');
    $ch->setMethod($this->_charsetMethod);
    $ch->transliterate('?');

    $ch2 = new CharsetHandler('sqltophp');
    $ch2->setMethod($this->_charsetMethod);
    $ch2->transliterate('?');
```

This should work if the other two methods you call staticaly are indeed static.